# Natural history / paleontology / geology dates

Tags: data-request, historical

I am looking for a comprehensive dataset of natural history dates, for a deep interactive timeline.

I'm interested in the dates of fossils, geological eras, estimated times for the apparition of different taxonomies, such as life itself, multicelular organisms and so on.

I imagine I will have to combine several sources, but in any case I am not interested in detailed descriptions, only dates.

Comment: From Wikidata: https://w.wiki/YcR

Comment: Thank you, I've worked with Wikidata but it's still too far away to be actually usable in a visualization (incomplete, mixed fiction with reality, no hierarchy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[World Digital Library](https://www.wdl.org/en/)

Provides data of 19,147 items about 193 countries between 8000 BCE and 2000.

---

[Timelines Revisited](http://timelinesrevisited.github.io/supplemental/datasets/)

A Design Space and Considerations for Expressive Storytelling

---

Additional Sources:

I'm not sure if this helps but it might be worth taking a look at.

There is a paper for extracting the historical events data from Wikipedia.  Extraction of [Historical Events from Wikipedia](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1205/1205.4138.pdf)